# How do I have the react bind resetAction within my method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation with the react-native. When I invoke `this.props.navigation.dispatch (resetAction)` inside the `render()` works. Already inside `Buttonpress()` no. My goal is to go to another route when Parse Server authenticates the user and reset the routes.

*Translated automatically.*

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Container, Content, Form, Item, Input, Button, Text} from 'native-base';
var Parse = require('parse/react-native');

import {NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation'

const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'Main'})]
})

export default class Auth extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: ''
    };
    this.Buttonpress = this.Buttonpress.bind(this);
  }
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Hedone'
  };

  Buttonpress() {
    Parse.initialize("APPLICATION_ID");
    Parse.serverURL = 'http://192.168.25.18:1337/parse'

    Parse.User.logIn(this.state.username, this.state.password, {
      success: function(user) {
        // Do stuff after successful login.
        () => this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
        console.warn("Certo")
      },
      error: function(user, error) {
        // The login failed. Check error to see why.
        console.warn("Errado");
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <Form>
            <Item>
              <Input placeholder="Username" onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({username: text})}/>
            </Item>
            <Item last>
              <Input placeholder="Password" onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})}/>
            </Item>
          </Form>

          <Button block onPress={this.Buttonpress}>
            <Text>Entrar</Text>
          </Button>

          <Button block onPress={() => navigate('Up')}>
            <Text>Inscrever-se</Text>
          </Button>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `bind` your function to the current context because it will be called from somewhere else, where the `this != this` because it's inside another context. You only have to do it if you want to use some variables/functions from the current `this` context.

```
Parse.User.logIn(this.state.username, this.state.password, {
    // needs to be bind because you want use 
    // `this.props` from the current context
    success: function (user) {
        // Do stuff after successful login.
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
        console.warn("Certo")
    }.bind(this),
    // this doesn't need to be bind, because it 
    // doesn't use something from this context
    error: function (user, error) {
        // The login failed. Check error to see why.
        console.warn("Errado");
    } 
});
```